# Efficient way to get all commits on a given day *and* their branch using Github API

Tags: git, github, github-api

I'm trying to get all the commits on a repo for a particular day. I also want to know the branch that each commit was on.

I'm looking for an efficient way to get this information using the github api.

Currently I'm fetching all the branches for a repo, then paging all the commits on that branch and filter in memory the commits from a certain date. Obviously with a lot of branches/commits this gets really inefficient.

ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Git commits aren't "on" any branch, and Git doesn't track the branch where a commit was first created. Branches are pointers to commits, and earlier commits may be reachable by a branch.

GitHub's API lets you [list commits by date using the `since` and `until` parameters](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/), but I don't see any way to get information about branches that contain a commit.

If you have an interesting commit, you *can* see the branches that currently contain it on the command line using `git branch --contains <hash>`, but this isn't the same as the branch that was active when the commit was created.

A bash loop like this should get you close to what you want:

```bash
for COMMIT in $(git log \
                    --since '2014-02-25' \
                    --until '2014-02-27' \
                    --pretty=format:'%h'); do

    echo $COMMIT && git branch --contains $COMMIT;
done
```

The output should be something like this:

```
abcd123
* master
  develop
1234abc
  develop
1234567
* master
```

You'll just have to update your local copy before running it.